# How to get the paremeters when I have a given data and formula in r?

Tags: r

I have a data frame like below,

```
structure(list(`Plot No.` = c(11, 12, 13, 14, 21, 22, 11, 12, 13, 14, 21, 22, 23, 11, 12, 13, 14, 21, 22, 23), Sample_ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), Treatment = c("A", "D", "TD", "T", "CO2", "DCO2", "A", "D", "TD", "T", "CO2", "DCO2", "TCO2", "A", "D", "TD", "T", "CO2", "DCO2", "TCO2"), T = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25), `R (µg CO2-C/g dry soil/hr)` = c(0.0224577914447771, 0.0179442829609729, 0.02688584916844, 0.0330002622240527, 0.0567148195871392, 0.0355053037352641, 0.0778264447670878, 0.0716472116716462, 0.119423848928993, 0.148338665254101, 0.190316253331465, 0.132496405855809, 0.0977254791656324, 0.241058563330705, 0.241395505291938, 0.341614787593164, 0.461344596068699, 0.585524319295799, 0.383691841463553, 0.31883194104183)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I also have a formula for these data to fit, which is:

```
R= a*exp^(b*T)   (1)
Q10=exp^(10*b)   (2)
```

I want to calculate the values of Q10, so firstly, I need to get the values of coefficients a and b through the given dataset of R and T. Then using the parameter b to calculate Q10.

I don't really know how to realize this in R. Hope some could give me some hints. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this with `nls` (Nonlinear Least Squares), since the model you describe is not linear. First, I rename `R (µg CO2-C/g dry soil/hr)` to `R`.

```
df <- structure(list(`Plot No.` = c(11, 12, 13, 14, 21, 22, 11, 12, 13, 14, 21, 22, 23, 11, 12, 13, 14, 21, 22, 23), Sample_ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), Treatment = c("A", "D", "TD", "T", "CO2", "DCO2", "A", "D", "TD", "T", "CO2", "DCO2", "TCO2", "A", "D", "TD", "T", "CO2", "DCO2", "TCO2"), T = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25), `R (µg CO2-C/g dry soil/hr)` = c(0.0224577914447771, 0.0179442829609729, 0.02688584916844, 0.0330002622240527, 0.0567148195871392, 0.0355053037352641, 0.0778264447670878, 0.0716472116716462, 0.119423848928993, 0.148338665254101, 0.190316253331465, 0.132496405855809, 0.0977254791656324, 0.241058563330705, 0.241395505291938, 0.341614787593164, 0.461344596068699, 0.585524319295799, 0.383691841463553, 0.31883194104183)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df$R <- df$`R (µg CO2-C/g dry soil/hr)`
```

Fit your model with `nls` (we have to provide it start values, I guessed these).

```
nlsfit <- nls(R ~ a*exp(b*T), data = df, start = list(a = 0.1, b = 0.1))

coefs <- coef(nlsfit)
coefs

#          a          b 
# 0.02093579 0.11467305
```

Check the fit:

```
plot(df$T, df$R)
lines(df$T, coefs[["a"]]*exp(coefs[["b"]]*df$T))
```

[image]

And then we can calculate `Q10`

```
Q10 <- exp(10*coefs[["b"]])
Q10

# 3.147884
```